# How do you validate Hive metastore uri

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

As part of an application , I need to validate Hive metastore Uris entered by user for their Hive. 
I wondered what all validation can be performed on String to validate if that is correct Hive Metastore URI

Any suggestions.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

MetaStore uri specified by `hive.metastore.uris` generally will be in this format:

```
thrift://n.n.n.n:9083
file:///var/metastore/metadb/
```

So I suggest you write a regular expression to match the possibilities also keep in mind that `hive.metastore.uris` property takes in comma separated values so match for more than one occurrence.

After you have done the basic validation, you could also try and establish a connection to the specified thrift port and see if that's valid as well.

Comment: So , do you mean if absolutely correct to  validate if input String starts with either "thrift://" or "file:///"?

Comment: Yeah. But if I were you I would also double check if the port is listening on the remote system.